# Android - Exceptions while trying to create SurfaceView and use for camera app

Tags: android, camera

I've been trying to code a camera app on Eclipse for Android using the API - I got this example from the link below, but the app seems to crash with a Nullpointerexception while creating the SurfaceView (called preview below).

Really really appreciate any help.. am trying to learn the android camera API and stuck on this for the whole day!

**These are a few lines from MainWindow.java which is the main Activity...  it outputs 1 and 2 and then terminates.**

```
    Log.i(TAG, "1");
    preview = new Preview(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "2 " + R.id.preview);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
    Log.i(TAG, "3");

    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    Log.i(TAG, "4");
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "5");
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,jpegCallback);
        }
    });
```

**These are the first few lines of Preview.java**

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = "PreviewClass";

SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera camera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    Log.i(TAG, "11");   
    mHolder = getHolder();
    Log.i(TAG, "12");
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "13");
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(TAG, "trying pre 15");
    camera = Camera.open();
    try
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "15");
```

Comment: What is it that's null? And what does this line do: `((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);` ?

Comment: Hello Keysr, I tried to find that out.. when I output "preview" I got an ID type value and when I output R.id.preview  I get 2131034113..so both of them don't look like Null. Not sure what else in that line could be null! 

Also FYI - Preview(Context context) does run - I get 11/12/13 outputted.

Comment: The logcat will tell you exactly what's null.

Comment: hi, ok i've moved beyond that point. apparently in the manifest , the permission for camera needs to be outside of the application tags.

what i now get is - a crash at this line - 

camera = Camera.open();

Comment: the error in logcat is - 
10-02 20:55:11.810 W/CameraService(   90): CameraService::connect X (pid 5503) rejected (existing client).
10-02 20:55:11.810 D/AndroidRuntime( 5503): Shutting down VM
10-02 20:55:11.810 W/dalvikvm( 5503): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40170760)
10-02 20:55:11.820 E/AndroidRuntime( 5503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 20:55:11.820 E/AndroidRuntime( 5503): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Comment: Post the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: Keyser, thanks.. Ive been able to move ahead now. will close this question. thanks for your interest.